# How to call onClick event on fragment views

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working on an application in which i have one fragment class and another is MainActivity class. In MainActivity.java i am loading the Fragment class dynamically. Now when the Fragment class is loaded i want to put an Onclick event on Fragment class views.

My code snippet are as follows.
**MainHandlerFragment.java**

```
public class MainHandlerFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_detail, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void navigateToAnotherActivity(){    // I am not able to call this method
       startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),  OrganizationActivity.class).putExtra("User",user));
   }
}
```

**home_detail.xml**

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_top_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_layout"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:onClick="navigateToAnotherActivity()"       // I am not able to call this method
    >
```

Is there anyway to get onclick fired when a view of dynamically loaded fragment is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_detail, container, false);

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.home_top_layout);

         rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),  OrganizationActivity.class).putExtra("User",user));
          }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.home_top_layout);

 layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
     startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),  OrganizationActivity.class).putExtra("User",user));
     }
});
```

and remove  `android:onClick="navigateToAnotherActivity()"`

Comment: It has no button in his layout, or it seems so

Answer (score 1):

First you are not calling correctly in your XML to your function, change

```
android:onClick="navigateToAnotherActivity()"
```

to

```
android:onClick="navigateToAnotherActivity"
```

Doing this way you should also change your function to

```
public void navigateToAnotherActivity(View v)
```

in order to get called.

Anyway, Android discourages this, and it will probably become a deprecated way of calling a function, so I would recommend you trying the following:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.home_top_layout);

rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) {
    navigateToAnotherActivity();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class MainHandlerFragment extends Fragment
 {
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_detail, container, false);
        public void navigateToAnotherActivity()
           {    // I am not able to call this method 
                startActivity(newIntent(getActivity(),OrganizationActivity.class).putExtra("User",user));
        }
    return view;
   }
```

}